# jquery .load() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

i can't seem to get jquery's .load() function to work.  must be something simple i'm missing...basically just trying to load a fragment of more.html into index.html.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("jquery script executing...");
            $('#foo').load('more.html #bar', loadComplete);
        });

        function loadComplete (response, status, xhr) {
            alert("load complete.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        foo foo foo
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**more.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>More</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bar">
        bar bar bar
    </div>
</body>
```

i see both the alerts -- the script is being executed, and the callback is being called (i.e. the load is completing).  however, the contents of  do not change.  i've tried on safari, chrome, and firefox (all on OSX).  there must be something obvious i'm missing...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The load function is broken in jquery 1.5 release. You can find the bug ticket at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8125. This is fixed in version 1.5.1. You can find the very latest jquery release with all the latest fixes including load() at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js

Comment: aiaiaiai.  well that would explain it then.  tried posting the same question on the jquery forum and got nothing.  i knew stackoverflow would give me love.  thanks!

Comment: 1.5.1 minified form Google CDN: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: load in jquery 1.6.2 is still broken.