# jQuery load a page and add only body part in my current page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use both `$.ajax` or `.load()` functions to load a page by ajax and than add its content replacing my current `$('body').html()`. The problem is than when I try to do it jquery will add everything (included the content of `<head></head>` in my body).

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/somepage.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
  }
});
```

or

```
$('body').load('/somepage.html');
```

The result will be something like

```
<body>
  <-- Here starts the content of the head -->
  <title>....</title>
  <script src="..."></script>
  <link src="..."></link>
  <meta></meta>
  <-- Here ends the content of the head -->
  <-- Here starts the real body content -->
  <div>........</div>
  <-- Here ends the body content -->
</body>
```

How can I avoid this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery `load` docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) loading a page fragment is done as follows:

```
$('body').load('/somepage.html body');
```

By adding a second option to the `url` argument you can control what get loaded.  You can also use css selectors in the second part such as `#someId` or `.someClass`.

Comment: except, that doesnt seem to work for <body>, since it is stripped from the result. $.get() does load the body, but doesnt have the page fragment trick.