# background-image: url not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am encountering is that when I use javascript to get the html file inside another html file, the background image turns invisible. But when I open the file with the background image the image is visible.

To make this understandable, I want to include *second.html* (with background image) in *first.html* using javascript without the image being invisible.

**First.html (main)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script> 
            $(function(){
                $("#second").load("second.html");
            });
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="second"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Second.html (with image)**

```
<body style="background-image: url('img/dashboard-layout.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #303032;">
    <!--Code goes here-->
</body>
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271316/jquery-load-body-from-external-html

Comment: a page can't have multiple body tags

Comment: Not sure that loading `body` tag into another document is a good idea regardless

Comment: try with removing body tag from second and use div instead

Comment: The browser might be removing the nested inner `<body>` tag.

Comment: @Guru, the strange thing is when I change the <body style="..."> to <div style="..."> the background turns invisible...

Comment: why don't you load your second html in `iframe` instead of div??

Comment: yes Iframe is good solution. If you used div then you need to set height for both divs. container and in second.html file see my ans below.

Comment: @Guru, your answer below worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working example 
first.html

```
<html>
  <head>
```

```
    <script> 
       $(function(){
            $("#second").load("second.html");
        });
    </script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="second" style="height:100px;width:100%;"></div>
   </body>
```

second.html

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100%;background-image: url('http://blogs.atlassian.com/wp-content/uploads/01-new-icons.png'); background-color: #303032;">
```

Note that div has default height = 0px  you need to set height for divs to work this eg.