# Calling .load() with selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done a fair bit of research on the subject and I just can't figure out why this isn't working the way it should. I have a form that a user fills out with an Amazon product ID (ASIN), and then I convert that product ID into a URL and then `.load()` that URL on my page. The problem is that when I use a selector with `.load()` to load just a portion of the page, the `.load()` doesn't do anything.

When I remove the selector and `.load()` with just the URL, `.load()` works. Here is my code:

```
<div id = "html" style = "display: none;"></div>
<input id = "url" type = "text" size = "100"></input>
<button id = "load">Load</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var theURL;

$('#load').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#url').val().length < 14) 
        theURL = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/' + $('#url').val() + ' #dp';
    else
        theURL = $('#url').val() + ' #dp';
    $('#html').load(theURL);
});
</script>
```

So for example, `theURL` would be `http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00J4GIRH4 #dp`, and when I have the  `#dp` selector in the URL `.load()` won't pull anything (verified by checking the `#html` element after invoking `.load()`). When the `#dp` selector is removed and `theURL` is `http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00J4GIRH4`, `.load()` works fine.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: assuming that you don't have an element with 'html' as it's ID, and you are actually after the top level html node.. is this not what you want instead? $('html').load(theURL);

Comment: @tymeJV I'm getting a `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error but I'm not sure if it's related. The URL it gives me in connection with that error doesn't seem to be an URL that I put in, so I'm assuming the error might be the result of a script running from the page I'm trying to load and that's why it's saying file not found. @Michael No, I'm trying to load the code into a hidden <div> with `id= "html"`.

Comment: okay, if it's a class it needs to be .html

Comment: Run `console.log(theURL)` right before the `load` call - is it what you think it is?

Comment: @tymeJV So I did that just now and `theURL` seems to be fine as I'm getting a value of `http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00J4GIRH4 #dp`. I believe the selector I'm using should be correct as well, if you go to that page the <body> has a class of `dp` which is the selector I'm using. Not sure what could be causing the issue, going to keep playing around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id="dp"` is on the `body` element in the Amazon page. The `#` reference supplied to `load()` will search the descendants of the loaded panel. Not the `body` element itself.

Try target a child element, or forget the selector as you get `body` back by default.

Comment: I see, so maybe I should try a selector that is inside the `body`? I would prefer to use the selector to prevent the scripts on Amazon's page from running on my page

Comment: Your could try `id="a-page`. If you view the source of the Amazon page it has very little in it. The rest is loaded dynamically *to stop people using content from their site* :)

Comment: If you want to know better ways of getting "the content you require", that is another question (that I do have considerable experience with). :)

Comment: This is actually the first program that I've tried making after learning Javascript on my own so I would love to hear more and learn something new. Do you mean gathering info from Amazon specifically or just gathering info in general? Please tell me more :)

Comment: From Amazon and other sites.I use a combination of WatiN with CSQuery to automate a browser. All content on the pages is intact that way, but you need to store the relevant parts on your own server (as you should).